# How do I solve these absolute value equations?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How do I solve these?
$$|-2w-4|<12$$

and

$$(-1/3)|6-5x|+2<1$$

for the first problem i got $-8<w<4$
is that right?

Comment: $$|A|<B\iff -B<A<B$$

Comment: @Chelsea, yes that is correct, but it would be more interesting if you show how you arrived at that. Was it by trial and error or analysis? We prefer the latter. Maybe you can add the details. Sometimes it helps to use something like WA to [*plot it*](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=abs%28-2+w+-+4%29+%3C+12). Regards

Answer (score 2):

You have $$(-1/3)|6-5x|+2<1$$ so $$(-1/3)|6-5x|<1-2$$ or $$(-1/3)|6-5x|<-1$$ Now we multiply both sides by $-3$ to have $$|6-5x|>3$$ There is an formula similar to what @Peter pointed you as follows: $$|A|>B\iff A>B~~\text{or}~~A<-B$$ Use it for the latter inequality to find that: $$x\in (9/5, +\infty)\cup (-\infty, 3/5)$$

Comment: do you do 6-5x>3 or 6-5x<-3 OR 6+5x>3 or 6+5x<-3?

Comment: @Chelsea: Sorry for the delay. I set $6-5x>3$ or $6-5x<-3$

Comment: Hello, dear Babak!

Comment: @amWhy: Hello dear one. :) How are you today? Is it started good? I hope so. :-)

Comment: Yes, so far so good: but it's only 5:35 a.m., so we'll see how the day goes ;-) I hope your day is going well!

Answer (score 0):

Hint:For the $|-2w-4|<12$ inequality you can rewrite it as $-12<-2w-4<12$ (since it is less than). Add four to both sides and we get $-8<-2w<16$ Thus $-8<-2w$ and $-2w<12$. Solve these and rewrite the inequality